# Why is su world executable?

Tags: sudo, su, headless

I have a headless server that is logged into remotely by multiple users. None of the other users are in the sudoers file, so they cannot obtain root via `sudo`. However, since the permissions on `su` are `-rwsr-xr-x` there's nothing stopping them from attempting to brute force the root password.

One could argue that if a user knows the root password they can compromise the system anyway, but I don't think this is the case. OpenSSH is configured with `PermitRootLogin no` and `PasswordAuthentication no`, and none of the other users have physical access to the server. As far as I can tell, the world execute permission on `/usr/bin/su` is the only avenue for users attempting to gain root on my server.

What's further puzzling to me in that it doesn't even seem useful. It allows me to run `su` directly instead of needing to do `sudo su`, but this is hardly an inconvenience.

Am I overlooking something? Is the world execute permission on `su` just there for historic reasons? Are there any downsides to removing that permission that I haven't encountered yet?

Comment: _"It allows me to run su directly instead of needing to do sudo su, but this is hardly an inconvenience."_ - What about systems without the optional `sudo` installed? I'd say it's a pretty big inconvenience there ;)

Comment: You can always restrict access for /bin/su, but remember to do the same for /usr/bin/pkexec also.

Comment: I can't seem to understand the motivation behind this question. It sounds like you were wondering why su needs to be world executable, but what would be the point of the alternative? That is, if su were only executable by root (?), what were you thinking it could be used for?

Comment: @DavidZ In fact, it is indeed useful for root! You can quickly switch users with it.

Comment: @val Yes, that's true. The fact that root can use su is not in question here. (On rereading, I can see how my previous comment would suggest otherwise, but that's not what I meant.) I'm curious what Altay_H thought about this before they asked this question though.

Comment: @DavidZ The advice I've heard is to always use `sudo` instead of `su`. I wasn't aware of `sudo -s` until I asked this question, so the only utility of `su` for me was to run `sudo su`. The only purpose of running `su` directly in my mind was to use the root password instead of the user password.

Comment: @Altay_H Ah, I see where you're coming from now. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

One point that is missing from [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535942) is that elevating to root is only one specific use for `su`.  The general purpose of su is to open a new shell under another user's login account.  That other user *could* be `root` (and perhaps most often is), but `su` can be used to assume *any* identity the local system can authenticate.

For example, if I'm logged in as user `jim`, and I want to investigate a problem that `mike` has reported, but which I am unable to reproduce, I might try logging in as `mike`, and running the command that is giving him trouble.

```
13:27:20 /home/jim> su -l mike
Password:(I type mike's password (or have him type it) and press Enter)
13:27:22 /home/mike> id
uid=1004(mike) gid=1004(mike) groups=1004(mike)
13:27:25 /home/mike> exit  # this leaves mike's login shell and returns to jim's
13:27:29 /home/jim> id
uid=1001(jim) gid=1001(jim) groups=1001(jim),0(wheel),5(operator),14(ftp),920(vboxusers)
```

Using the `-l` option of `su` causes it to simulate a full login (per the `man` page).

The above requires knowledge of `mike`'s password, however.  If I have `sudo` access, I can log in as `mike` even without his password.

```
13:27:37 /home/jim> sudo su -l mike
Password:(I type my own password, because this is sudo asking)
13:27:41 /home/mike>
```

In summary, the reason the permissions on the `su` executable are as you show, is because `su` is a **general-purpose tool** that is available to all users on the system.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Since I'm in the habit of using `sudo` I forgot that `su` can be used for more than just `sudo -s`. And without being a sudoer this would be the only way to switch users without altering ssh keys. For my use case this is another reason to remove the permission, but I understand now why the world execute permission is set by default. Thanks!

Comment: Another point is that `sudo`, too, can be used to assume the identity of a user other than `root`. It's simply allows finer grained control over who can do what as whom, including assuming another identity *without* the need for that identity's password.

Comment: Part of the confusion is that people think `su` stands for "super user", which it does, when no user is specified (or root is explicity specified) but it also stands for "switch user".  This second use of `su` is therefore easily forgotten.

Answer (score 21):

Historically (on non-GNU unices), it wasn't, or at least it manually checked if you were in a group called "wheel" permitted to `su`. The GNU version of `su` did not reproduce this functionality because of RMS's ideology about access control at the time:

```
Why GNU `su' does not support the `wheel' group
===============================================

   (This section is by Richard Stallman.)

   Sometimes a few of the users try to hold total power over all the
rest.  For example, in 1984, a few users at the MIT AI lab decided to
seize power by changing the operator password on the Twenex system and
keeping it secret from everyone else.  (I was able to thwart this coup
and give power back to the users by patching the kernel, but I wouldn't
know how to do that in Unix.)

   However, occasionally the rulers do tell someone.  Under the usual
`su' mechanism, once someone learns the root password who sympathizes
with the ordinary users, he or she can tell the rest.  The "wheel
group" feature would make this impossible, and thus cement the power of
the rulers.

   I'm on the side of the masses, not that of the rulers.  If you are
used to supporting the bosses and sysadmins in whatever they do, you
might find this idea strange at first.
```

You can find a lot more on the matter by Googling "wheel group rms" or similar.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The setting is intentional, historical, and this exactly is the reason for it. All the technical blabla is just that - blabla. You can absolutely reintroduce the "wheel" group in a modern Unix.

Answer (score 10):

> However, since the permissions on `su` are `-rwsr-xr-x` there's nothing stopping them from attempting to brute force the root password.

Yes. Assuming your usual Linux system, the `pam_unix.so` module does delay a failed authentication attempt by ~two seconds, but I don't think there's anything to stop simultaneous attempts.

Failed attempts are logged of course:

```
Aug 16 22:52:33 somehost su[17387]: FAILED su for root by ilkkachu
```

Brute-forcing a password should show up prominently in the logs, if you have any kind of system for monitoring them. And if you have untrusted local users, maybe you should. Untrusted local users could also attempt to use any local-only privilege escalation exploits, and they're much more common than remote privilege escalation.

> What's further puzzling to me in that it doesn't even seem useful.

Of course it's useful, it allows you to elevate yourself to `root`, if you know the password.

> It allows me to run `su` directly instead of needing to do `sudo su`, but this is hardly an inconvenience.

`sudo su` is somewhat redundant. There's no need to use two programs that are meant to allow you to run programs as another user, one is quite enough. Just use `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` (or `sudo /bin/bash` etc.) if you want to run shell.

> Am I overlooking something? Is the world execute permission on su just there for historic reasons?

See above. Well, not all systems have `sudo` as an alternative, I'm not sure if you consider that historic.

> Are there any downsides to removing that permission that I haven't encountered yet?

Not really, no as far as I know. I *think* some systems have `su` set so that only members of a particular group ("`wheel`") can run it. You can do the same to `sudo` if you like (`chown root.sudousers /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4710 /usr/bin/sudo`).

Or you could just remove either or both of the programs if you don't need them. Though on Debian, `su` comes with the `login` package, so it's probably not a good idea to remove the package as a whole. (And pairing `login` and `su` together like that does seem somewhat historic.)

Comment: BSD systems require users to be in the `wheel` group to use `su`. There are some BSD systems (I can only speak for OpenBSD) that does not ship with `sudo` at all (it's a 3rd-party package). OpenBSD has `doas` which is a reimplementation of the basics of `sudo`, but it's disabled by default upon installing a fresh system.

Comment: @Kusalananda You only have to be in `wheel` if you want to `su` to root.  Any account can `su` to any non-root account for which they have the password, regardless of their membership in the `wheel` group.

Comment: I run 'sudo su -' to ensure that the root shell I get is a full root login, without a polluted environment from my user account.  The default sudoers on RHEL includes quite a few environment variables that are executable (such as PS1).

Comment: @jsbillings, hmm, ok. Does `su` clear the environment then? It doesn't seem to do that on Debian...

Comment: “su -“ does in every Linux I know of. Mind the dash.

Comment: @jsbillings: Doesn't `sudo -i` do the same thing? Or does that fail to fully clean the environment?

Answer (score 7):

You already have some good answers, but there's one part of your post they don't address.

> As far as I can tell, the world execute permission on /usr/bin/su is the only avenue for users attempting to gain root on my server.

That's a dangerous assumption. If you've set a good password for root, then it in most cases is far more likely that a successful privilege escalation will be due to the exploitation of a bug in the kernel or a setuid binary (you can of course also remove the setuid bit from those, but `passwd` is setuid, and if you want to high security you should also offer that to your users, and denying them the option of changing their password is not compatible with that).

Answer (score 1):

su needs to be world-executable so everyone can run it.
In many systems, it can be used to change to another user, by supplying their password.

If you are concerned about someone bruteforcing the root password, you could just disable it. (make the hash invalid so no given password can match it)

I don't know about the consensus, but I'd consider being able to log in as root directly a security problem in and of itself.

Answer (score -2):

The other answers are correct saying "su" allows you to log into accounts other than root.

One note about "sudo su" though. This actually allows you to log into the root account without knowing the root password. You do have to know the password of the account you run sudo with as well as have that account be in the sudoers file.

Comment: That depends entirely on whether `sudoers` has `targetpw` or `rootpw` set.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `su` being executable by all.