# I'm not in "wheel" group, but I can "su -"

Tags: group, su, bsd

I don't understand. In BSD if I want to run `su -`, I have to add myself to `wheel` group.
Is this not true in Linux?

```
[test@centos ~]$ uname -a
Linux centos 4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64 ...
[test@centos ~]$ cat /etc/group | grep wheel
wheel:x:10:
[test@centos ~]$ cat /etc/group | grep test
test:x:1001:
[test@centos ~]$ su -
Password: 
Last login: Wed Oct 14 ...
[root@centos ~]# whoami
root
```

Comment: A search engine is good for finding answers before posting a question. Have a look at the answer hidden within https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535936/why-is-su-world-executable   Welcome aboard!

Comment: Membership of the wheel group is required by the BSD-authored su command. Membership of the wheel group is not required by the GNU-authored su command in their coreutils programs. Richard Stallman gives reasons at https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/coreutils-4.5.4/html_node/coreutils_149.html  When PAM support was added to GNU's su, that behaviour was configured as the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When invoked as aforementioned, the `su` command will ask for a root/superuser password; group membership is irrelevant, as long as you know the password. Now, if you were using `sudo su`, you could assign group(s) superuser rights; wheel and sudo are (2) groups most often used out-of-the-box, especially on single-user systems.

Comment: Yes, but you specifically asked "Is this not true in Linux?" - so no reason for the downvotes, as this answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the Linux distribution, but in CentOS, there's no special relationship between `su` and `wheel` out of the box:

```
% docker run --rm -it centos:8
[root@58212abdad65 /]# grep wheel /etc/pam.d/ -r
/etc/pam.d/su:# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
/etc/pam.d/su:#auth     sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
/etc/pam.d/su:# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
/etc/pam.d/su:#auth     required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

As you can see, you can configure it to behave like the BSD you use.

In some other distros, the first option might be enabled (allowing `wheel` users to `su` without needing a password), but I don't remember which ones.

Comment: i can confirm, that on ubuntu, ubuntu server, raspberrypi os everyone can use "su" if you have the root password.